# WordPress blog on subdirectory .htaccess redirect

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have a Joomla website on root-level, and wordpress blog on /blog .

Inside root-level .htaccess, I need to implement non-www to www redirect, such as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, this causes a problem when going to www.example.com/blog (withoug trailing "/" at the end). I get redirected to http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/php53.cgi/blog/index.php

The php53.cgi file is there to turn on PHP 5.3 version. This is the content of that file:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=3
exec /hsphere/shared/php53/bin/php-cgi
```

This is the .htaccess inside /blog directory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to redirect non-`www` to `www` on both `.htaccess` since the later `.htaccess` will overwrite your Joomla `.htaccess` rules.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

---

As for the blog not ending with `/` you could try this rule at your Joomla `.htaccess`:

```
# Redirect /blog to /blog/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+blog([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog$ /blog/? [R=301,L]
```

NOTE: I am using `%{THE_REQUEST}` because since I don't know what rules you have on your Joomla `.htaccess`, the above will most likely work on all cases.

But you could also do it in a simpler way but that will not work in all cases depending on what other rules you have:

```
# Redirect /blog to /blog/
RewriteRule ^blog$ /blog/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and got it working. Apparently I only needed to add non-www to www redirect inside the /blog/.htaccess .

Comment: @GeorgeC glad it worked for u ;) I was thinking that was the issue for you but just in case I've also added the other method.